# Non-exhaustive patterns in function combadd1

Tags: haskell

already added count - 1 > 0 terminate it , no infinity loop, do not know why it has this pattern

```
./hello
hello: main.hs:(95,1)-(102,9): Non-exhaustive patterns in function combadd1
```

expect to add one of combination of output to output of logic table
though combination is not full combination, would like to glue back 
one kind of combination to output of logic table

code:

```
combadd :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int,Int, Int, Int) -> Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
combadd [] (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9) count = []
combadd ((x1,x2,x3):xs) (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9) count =
  if x1 == 0 && x2 == 0 
  then (x1,x2,x3) : combadd xs (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9) count
  else
    if count == 9 then
      (x1,x2,x3+a2) : combadd xs (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9) (count-1)
    else if count == 8 then 
      (x1,x2,x3+a3) : combadd xs (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9) (count-1)
    else if count == 7 then 
      (x1,x2,x3+a4) : combadd xs (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9) (count-1)
    else if count == 6 then 
      (x1,x2,x3+a5) : combadd xs (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9) (count-1)
    else if count == 5 then 
      (x1,x2,x3+a6) : combadd xs (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9) (count-1)
    else if count == 4 then 
      (x1,x2,x3+a7) : combadd xs (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9) (count-1)
    else if count == 3 then 
      (x1,x2,x3+a8) : combadd xs (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9) (count-1)
    else if count == 2 then 
      (x1,x2,x3+a9) : []
    else
      []

combadd1 :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
combadd1 [(x1,x2,x3)] ((a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9):ys) count po =
  if count == po
  then combadd [(x1,x2,x3)] (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9) 9
  else
     if count-1 > 0 then 
       combadd1 [(x1,x2,x3)] ys (count-1) po
     else
       []

comb0 :: [(Int, Int, Int)]
comb0 = do
   a <- [0,1,2]
   b <- [0,1,2]
   return (a, b, max a b)

comb :: [(Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)]
comb = do
   a1 <- [0]
   a2 <- [0,1]
   a3 <- [0]
   a4 <- [0,1] 
   a5 <- [0,1]
   a6 <- [0]
   a7 <- [0]
   a8 <- [0]
   a9 <- [0]
   return (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9)

main :: IO()
main = do 
  mapM_ print $ combadd1 comb0 comb 3 3
```

Comment: hey you are posting quite a few questions all in that similar matter here - maybe instead you could try and explain what you are really trying to do - because your questions/functions get more and more complicated and there will most certainly be a much better way to solve your original problem than working with **9-tuples** (you should never do this - you need a genius to remember what every one of those 9 components are for when trying to understand your code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`combadd1` doesn't have any definition in case the given list is empty, or in case the given list contains more than one element. Maybe the type of the function is not quite appropriate - why does it take a list in the first place? It may be that you can fix this issue by changing the type such that a 3-tuple is expected as the first argument (instead of a list of 3-tuples).

Comment: It lacks a case for when there is more than one element as well.

Comment: @chi True, good catch! I incorporated that into my answer now.